# selected view in UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How can i detect when user select an item of tab bar?
I want to run some commands on each time, when user select the second or the thirt tab bar view.

(I have a tab bar based project, and the viewcontrollers for tabBar items are selected in interface builder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem with using"viewWillApear:(BOOL)animated" method in each view-s of tabBar.

Comment: viewWillApear:(BOOL)animated not getting called

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in `UITabBarDelegate` called:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

You can certainly do what you want with ;)

Answer (score 0):

A tab bar and tab bar controller both have delegate methods: `UITabBarDelegate` and `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. You can use the `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method of the UITabBarDelegate to detect when the user selects different items on the bar.